# Linux: Real-time Battery Power Usage

Tags: linux, power-management, battery

Is there a package for getting an accurate reading on the current total battery power usage in Watts on any system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at [powertop](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/): It displays various information about power usage in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Modern linux kernels should have this information exposed via `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now` and possibly other `BAT*` devices for multi-battery system.

As I wanted real-time power usage monitor, `powertop`'s refresh rate wasn't enough for me. I used following one-liner to output pretty-printed value each 0.1 second:

```bash
while true; do echo $(echo "scale=6; $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now) / 1000000" | bc -l) Watt; sleep 0.1s; done;
```

Helped me to discover, that laptop eats a bit of battery even in idle state (a different problem though):

```
...
0 Watt
0 Watt
0 Watt
0 Watt
0 Watt
0 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
.031000 Watt
0 Watt
0 Watt
0 Watt
0 Watt
0 Watt
0 Watt
...
```